# parallel fortran program willl sleep at a certain time

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, openmp

Recently I had to change a serial program written in fortran to a parallel version to make it faster to get the result. But I met some problems.

I'm using ubuntu os and gfortran compiler, and as for the parallel API, I'm using OpeMP. In the previous (serial) version, I use many modules to share the data, but in openmp version, I make the variables threadprivate attribute, and some of these variables has allocatable attribute. In the previous version, I allocate the space for the variable before the do-loop, but in the openmp version, if I do the same, the program will report an error as invalid memory reference, although I give it the threadprivate attribute. So I allocate the variable in the loop and deallocate it also in the loop. And I make that do-loop in a parallel region. It give no error and the program can run. But there is another problem. As it runs about 800min cpu time, and I use ps -ux command to see the status of this parallel program, its status changes from Rl to Sl. I search for the meaning of S, and it represent

> Interruptible sleep (waiting for an event to complete)

So why this problem appears? Is it because I frequently alloc and free the space? The following is the sample code:

```
module variables
real, dimension(:), allocatable, save :: a
real, dimension(:,:), allocatable, save :: b
!$omp threadprivate(a,b)
integer, parameter :: n=100
contains
   subroutine alloc_var
   integer :: status
   allocate(a(100),stat=status)
   allocate(b(100:100),stat=status)
   end subroutine
   subroutine free_var
   integer :: status
   deallocate(a,stat=status)
   deallocate(b,stat=status)
   end subroutine
end module
```

for other subroutines, there are some using variable a and b.

```
subroutine cal_sth
use variables, only a
...
end subroutine
```

for the serial version main program

```
program main
implicit none   
external :: cal_sth
use variables, only alloc_var,free_var
integer :: i, j
call alloc_var
do j=1, count1
...
other expresion ...
do i=1, count2
   call cal_sth
end do
end do
call free_var
end program
```

for parallel region,

```
program main
implicit none  
external :: cal_sth 
use variables, only alloc_var, free_var
integer :: i,j
!$omp parallel do private(i,j)
do j=1, count1
...
other expression ...
do i=1, count2
   call alloc_var
   call cal_sth
   if (logical expression) then
       call free_var
       cycle
   end if
   call free_var
end do
end do
end program
```

Comment: why don't you just initialise `a` and `b` once and for all inside a dedicated `parallel` region? Like: `!$omp parallel` `call alloc_var` `!$omp end parallel`

Answer (score 2):

Either split the combined `parallel do` directive and rewrite the parallel loop so:

```
!$omp parallel
call alloc_var
!$omp do
do i=1, count
   call cal_sth
end do
!$omp end do
call free_var
!$omp end parallel
```

or use dedicated parallel regions as per Gilles' comment:

```
program main
implicit none  
external :: cal_sth 
use variables, only alloc_var, free_var
integer :: i
!$omp parallel
call alloc_var
!$omp end parallel
...
!$omp parallel do
do i=1, count
   call cal_sth
end do
!$omp end parallel do
...
! other OpenMP regions
...
!$omp parallel
call free_var
!$omp end parallel
end program
```

Comment: There is another problem if I split the `parallel do` directive, because in the parallel region, there are some circumstances I need to `cycle` the loop, which I forget to add in the sample code. And additionally, there is not only one loop. I'll change the sample code, and please see it again.

Answer (score 1):

With your updated code, I think you have two different path to explore for improving performance:

- The memory allocation: As previously mentioned, the calls to `alloc_var` and `free_var` only need to be made in a `parallel` region, but definitely not necessarily inside the `do` loop. By splitting the `parallel do` into a `parallel`, then a `do`, it gives you room for calling `alloc_var` prior to entering the loop, and calling `free_var` after exiting it. And the potential early exit from the inner loop, possibly necessitating a release / re-allocation of the memory isn't by itself a constraint preventing you from doing this. (see the code below for an example on how this can be done)
- The scheduling: the early terminations of some of you inner iterations might translate into some load imbalance between threads. This could explain the waiting times you experiment. Explicitly setting the scheduling to `dynamic` might permit to reduce this effect and improve performance. This will need to be experimented a bit with to find the best scheduling policy to apply, but `dynamic` seems a good starting point.

So here is your code as it could look like once these two idea implemented:

```
program main
    implicit none  
    external :: cal_sth 
    use variables, only alloc_var, free_var
    integer :: i,j

    !$omp parallel schedule(dynamic)
    call alloc_var
    !$omp do private(i,j)
    do j=1, count1
        ...
        other expression ...
        do i=1, count2
            call cal_sth
            if (logical expression) then
                !uncomment these only if needed for some reasons
                !call free_var
                !call alloc_var
                cycle
            end if
        end do
    end do
    !$omp end do
    call free_var
    !$omp end parallel
end program
```

Comment: I still have the problem that at a certain time the progress goes to sleep if I remove the `schedule` clause. But if I add this clause, the program will jump some loops, like from j=0 to j=6, j=1 to 5 loop does not execute, do  you know why is this?